# Python TypeError: 'MyException' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
# filename: auth.py

class DisabledAccountError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, uid):
        self.uid = uid

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.uid)


class DeletedAccountError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, uid):
        self.uid = uid

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.uid)

def login_validation(account): 
    if login_info.status == OBJECT_STATUS_DISABLED:
        raise DisabledAccountError(login_info.uid) # this is line 426

    if login_info.status == OBJECT_STATUS_DELETED:
        raise DeletedAccountError(login_info.uid)
```

But sometimes, the server will report some error like this:

`TypeError: 'DeletedAccountError' object is not callable`

But the stack trace was so weird:

```
TypeError: 'DeletedAccountError' object is not callable
  File "xxxxxx.py", line 104, in login_validation
    login_info = auth.login_validation(account)
  File "auth.py", line 426, in login_validation
    raise DisabledAccountError(login_info.uid)
```

How does this error happen?

Why the error is `DeletedAccountError` but the stack trace is `DisabledAccountError` ?

I can't reproduce the error by myself. I both tried to disable an account and delete an account. But it really happened in our production server.

Comment: We use `uwsgi` with multi-thread and multi-process.

Comment: This is weird indeed. Are you sure that there's nothing in the rest of your code that could be relevant to your issue? Is this really the complete traceback?

Answer (score 0):

We found the root case:

```
try:
    # some code
except auth.DeletedAccountError, auth.DisabledAccountError:
    pass
```

So stupid.

Comment: Nice puzzle. Clearly you are using Python 2, because the syntax `except ExceptionType, errorvar:` is no longer supported in Python 3. Can you take the time to spell out what happened, for the benefit of everyone else?